# Which event is raised when ANY item is selected in a WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

```
<ListBox
    x:Name="listBox"
    SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged">
</ListBox>
```

```
void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // This method is only called when a selection is changed. 
}
```

However, I need to call a function that executes even if the already selected item in the list box is clicked again (which would make it selected had it not already been).

I tried the Selected event handler but received this error in visual studio:

```
Error   CS1061  'ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no accessible extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is there any other event I might be missing?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown or any Mouse down event probably.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `.xaml` (assume ListBox item is `Grid`)

```xml
<ListBox
    x:Name="listBox"
    SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid PreviewMouseDown="listBox_OnPreviewMouseDown">
                            <!-- Content -->
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

2. In `.xaml.cs` (assume `MyListItemType` is the type of the item in `ListBox`)

```cs
private void listBox_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedItem = (sender as FrameworkElement)?.DataContext as MyListItemType;
    if (clickedItem != listBox.SelectedItem) return;
    // same item is selected
    // .. 
}

private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedItem = (sender as FrameworkElement)?.DataContext as MyListItemType;
    // new item is selected
    // .. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Example:**

```xml
    <UniformGrid>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <sys:String>QWERTY</sys:String>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                                 Handler="OnItemClick"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tBlock"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

```cs
        private int count = 0;
        private void OnItemClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            tBlock.Text += $"{count}: {((ListBoxItem)sender).Content}{Environment.NewLine}";
        }
```

**Second Example:**

```xml
        <ListBox SelectionChanged="OnSelection"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <sys:String>QWERTY</sys:String>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Char}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PART_TBlock" Text="{Binding}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="PART_Btn" Content="{Binding}" Click="OnReselection"
                                BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_TBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Btn" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tBlockReselection"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

```cs
        private void OnSelection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            tBlockReselection.Text += $"Selected: {((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem}{Environment.NewLine}";
        }

        private void OnReselection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tBlockReselection.Text += $"Reselected: {((Button)sender).Content}{Environment.NewLine}";
        }
```

**Third Example:**

```xml
        <ItemsControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                <sys:String>QWERTY</sys:String>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Char}">
                        <Button Content="{Binding}" Click="OnClickselection"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tBlockClickSelection"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

```cs
        private void OnClickselection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tBlockClickSelection.Text += $"ClickSelection: {((Button)sender).Content}{Environment.NewLine}";
        }
```